# Method Object is not Subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i'm trying to access a df using pandas and insert the value of the first item in a list i've created.

The line of code where it breaks is this:

```
df.insert[i,6,postalcode[1]]
```

the value of `postalcode[1]` is `'RG2 9GL'` and a string but I get the error

> Method Object is not Subscriptable

which i'm not entirely sure on.

Quite new to python so would love to learn where I am going wrong.
Cheers

Comment: Use `df.insert(i,6,postalcode[1])`, it is typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be typo error , try this

```
df.insert(i,6,postalcode[1])

Standard Syntax: DataFrame.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False)
```

Official Document: [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)
Example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1),  columns=["A"])
s.insert(1, "Team", "Any")
print(s)
```